# How to complete a sentence starting with "Just because..."

Tags: sentence

I often find myself starting a sentence with "Just because", as in "Just because I didn't respond to your invitation, that doesn't mean I don't want to attend."

But I never quite know how to finish it. Is it grammatical to finish it with "doesn't mean", "that doesn't mean", "it doesn't mean" etc.? The [first few Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22just%20because%20I%22%20-lyrics%20-book) tend to use one of those, but something about that usage always sounds slightly off to me (what is the "that" referring to?)

Comment: Yes. The _just_ is optional; it's merely an emphasizer. _(Just) because `S` doesn't mean `NP`_ is the idiom. `S` can be any tensed clause, and `NP` can be any noun phrase, including tensed _that_-clauses.

Comment: https://youtu.be/XFTnFhGuaBQ

Comment: I don't understand. You *did* finish the sentence in the question. And it makes sense. Are you asking if the sentence in the question is grammatical? It is.

Comment: @JasonBassford  I am.

Comment: Just because you are used to using it all the time does not mean it is not correct English.  You may try using the parts in reverse order for the sake of variety. "Please don't think that I don't want to attend. I just didn't respond to the invitation."

Comment: I think your example sentence would sound more natural without the "that" or comma.